# Calculate score for a quiz

Tags: calculus

I have a quiz with three questions

```
1. Question 1 - 1 Point
2. Question 2 - 5 Points
3. Question 3 - 10 Points
```

If my answers are incorrect for a question (1) and question (2) and the (3) answer is correct, I should receive a score - 62.5%.

I believe this is the right result, but how exactly can achieve this number?

I'd like to understand exactly how to calculate the score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to solve a rule of three $$S = \frac{S_0}{16}\times 100$$ where $S_0$ is the sum of the points of your correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

$(1)$ How many points are earned when answering only question #$3$ correctly?

$(2)$ How many total points are possible?

Divide the first the first answer by the second answer to obtain a fraction/decimal representation of the proportion $$\dfrac{\text{points earned}}{\text{total possible points}}.$$

Multiply this fraction/decimal by $100\%$ to obtain the desired percentage.